# How to setState in ComponentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, state, mount

I have something strange with a react app,

I used it in a django project and want to re-use it in a laravel project but it doesn't want to work properly ...

Here is the code of my component :

```
import React from "react"
import {LeftControl, RightControl, CountControl } from './controls'
import {Slide} from './slide'
import axios from "axios"

export default class Slider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items : [],
            active:0
        }
     }

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/coming')
        .then((res)=>{
            this.setState({ items: res.data, active: 0})
        });
    setInterval( () => {
        this.goToNextSlide()
    },5000);
}

goToPrevSlide = () => {
    const n = this.state.items.length
    if (this.state.active == 0) {
        this.setState({active : n-1})
    } else {
        this.setState({active: this.state.active - 1})
    }
}

goToNextSlide = () => {
    const n = this.state.items.length
    if (this.state.active == n-1){
        this.setState({active : 0})
    } else {
        this.setState({active: this.state.active +1})
    }
}

render(){
    return(
        <div className="slider">
            <div className="slider__controls">
                <CountControl active={this.state.active} length={this.state.items.length} />
                <LeftControl goToPrevSlide={this.goToPrevSlide} />
                <RightControl goToNextSlide={this.goToNextSlide}/>
            </div>
            <div className="slider__items">
                {
                    this.state.items
                        .map((item, i) => (
                            <Slide active={this.state.active} index={i} key={i} id={item.id} first_name={item.first_name} last_name={item.last_name} role={item.role} conference_date={item.conference_date} thumbnail={item.thumbnail} />
                        ))
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Uncommenting the setState in componentDidMount raise the following error :

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
in Slider
```

The component works well on my other project ...

Anyone would have an idea what is the problem ?

Thank you

Comment: Please, share full code of your component

Comment: Most likely your `Slider` is unmounted (closed/navigated away) before the `setState` call is executed, hence giving the error.

Comment: Edited my post so you have the full code, I don't see why my component would be unmounted, it's an html div render with : ReactDOM.render(<Slider />, document.getElementById('home-slider'))

Answer (score 2):

As riwu commented, you get the warning because the axios call and timer you define in `componentDidMount` try to set the state of `Slider` after it has been unmounted. Do the following instead:

```
export default class Slider extends React.Component {
    ...

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._isMounted = false;
        this.state = {
            items : [],
            active:0,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;

        axios.get('/coming')
            .then((res) => {
                if (this._isMounted) {
                    this.setState({ items: res.data, active: 0})
                }
            });

        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            this.goToNextSlide();
        }, 5000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }

    ...
}
```